# Wanted but not invoked Mockito

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, junit, mockito

Hello I am getting a `"Wanted but not invoked"` error for my `testRegLogin()` test, however the rest of my tests are all passing.
My tests are below. This code tests a `Login.java` code that checks details entered into a `JTextField` and then checks them against the database. If correct login occurs it invokes a `Controller` class.

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestLoginJunit {

   Login log = new Login();
   String username = "edwardc5";    
   String password = "case4";
   Robot r;
   JButton[] buttons = log.sendButton();

   //correct login for program expected outcome = new controller invoked
   @Test
   public void testCorrectLogin() throws AWTException {

        r=new Robot();
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(username);
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.delay(500);

        stringSelection= new StringSelection(password);
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        r.delay(500);

        buttons[0].doClick();
        r.delay(100);
        Controller controller = Mockito.spy(new Controller());
        verify(controller, times(1));
   }

   //testing wrong username outcome= error displayed and controller not invoked
   @Test
   public void testWrongUsernameLogin() throws AWTException {   
        Login login = mock(Login.class);
        r=new Robot();
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("ed");
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.delay(500);

        stringSelection= new StringSelection(password);
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        r.delay(500);

        buttons[0].doClick();
        r.delay(100);
        verify(login, never()).invokeController();
   }

   //testing cancel button outcome= window closes
   @Test
   public void testCancelLogin() throws AWTException {  
        Login login = mock(Login.class);
        r=new Robot();
        r.delay(500);
        buttons[2].doClick();
        r.delay(100);
        verify(login, never()).invokeController();
   }

   //testing registration button outcome = register is invoked
   @Test
   public void testRegLogin() throws AWTException { 
        Login login = mock(Login.class);    
        r=new Robot();
        buttons[1].doClick();
        r.delay(500);
        verify(login, times(1)).register();     
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What Mockito is tell you in your `testRegLogin()` method your expecting `login.register()` to be call one time but Mockito is tell you that it was never called. You can verify that by changing

`verify(login, times(1)).register();`

to

`verify(login, never()).register();`

Comment: I did as you suggested however now I am getting an  _"UnfinishedVerificationException"_, _"missing method call for verify(mock)"_. However it does pass if I run it on its own rather than the entire file.